# javascript check object properties begining with

Tags: javascript, object

How to select only the key's in object begining with certain character?
In mi case the key's begining with a dot ('.prop_2' and '.prop_4')

```
mi_obj = {
  'prop_1': 'value 1',
  '.prop_2': 'value 2',
  prop_3: 'value 3',
  '.prop_4': 'value 4'
}
```

I know it's possible with a "for" loop but no other better option?

Comment: `Object.keys(mi_obj).filter(a => a.startsWith("."));` would probably be the “better” option, but it depends on whether you need to support older browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could do a filter on the keys, which will return an array of the keys that start with dot

```
    Object.keys(mi_obj).filter(function(key) {
      return key.starsWith('.');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the simplest way is a simple for loop (as you stated).

But if you want another way (let's say it's elegant) you can take all the properties and use `filter` on them.

First, taking the properties of the object as an array:

```
Object.keys(mi_obj);
```

Then filtering them:

```
Object.keys(mi_obj).filter(function(x) {return x.startsWith("."); });
```

Or with a lambda expression:

```
Object.keys(mi_obj).filter(function(x) {(x) => x.startsWith("."));
```